# XSLT : Check for elements in sequence ignore case - if present node has to be removed

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML structure:

```
<ITEMS>
   <ITEM>
      <ITEMTYPE>FOO</ITEMTYPE>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <ITEMTYPE>BAR</ITEMTYPE>
   </ITEM>
</ITEMS>
```

I'll be passing sequence as parameter to the XSLT. If the ITEMTYPE is present in the sequence, the  node has to be **removed**. And it has to be processed in case-insensitive.

I'm newbie to XSLT. I've coded like below but not able to crack the case-insensitive.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="itemsToRemove"/>


    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <xsl:variable name="currentItemType">
            <xsl:value-of select="itemType"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="not(fn:index-of($itemsToRemove, $currentItemType))">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What has to be case-insensitive, the value of  `ITEMTYPE` comparisons, or the name of the element (as you have `ITEMTYPE` in your XML but `itemType` in your XSLT)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use case-insensitive value comparison then one way is using the `matches` function with the `i` flag:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="itemsToRemove" select="'foo'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM[$itemsToRemove[matches(., current()/ITEMTYPE, 'i')]]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

With http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvW the output then is

```
<ITEMS>

   <ITEM>
      <ITEMTYPE>BAR</ITEMTYPE>
   </ITEM>
</ITEMS>
```

Comment: Function current should have been resolved at compile time (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  net.sf.saxon.functions.CompileTimeFunction:41 (null)

@Martin Honnen: I'm hitting with this error when I run from a java program

Comment: Can you tell us which version of Saxon exactly you are using when you get that error? Does it also occur when you run the code with that Saxon version from the command line? It might be necessary that you create a new question where you show all the details to allow others to reproduce the problem.